Is there a general formula for the likelihood of the sum of multinomial outcome multiplied by a known array?
Let's say I have a multinomial of size N with bin probabilities p1, p2, and p3. The outcome of this multinomial is a vector, [a, b, c]. Let's further say this multinomial represents some sort of breeding animal, so p1 is the probability of 0 offspring, p2 is the probability of an individual having 1 offspring, and p3 is the probability of having 2 offspring.
[a, b, c] ~ Multinomial(N, [p1, p2, p3])

To get the full number of animals produced, we can multiply our result vector by a vector that represents how many offspring are produced per category and then sum the result, to get Z.
Z = [a, b, c]* [0, 1, 2]

Example:
I have 10 deer, and I know the probability of 0, 1 and 2 fawns is .1, .5 and .4 for this population. After breeding, I know there are 13 fawns produced. Can I estimate the likelihood of having 13 fawns produced given 10 deer?
[1, 5, 4] ~ Multinomial[10, [.1, .5, .4])
Z = 5 + 8 = 13
More generally, here's my question:
If I know Z, N, p1, p2, and p3, is it possible to estimate the likelihood of having Z as an outcome? If so, how is that calculated? Here I am assuming that the vector [a, b, c] is not observed.
Please note that I am a wildlife biologist, not a mathematician, so I am trying to understand this from a practical standpoint not a theoretical one. If there's a solution that approximates the likelihood, I would also be interested in that.
What I've tried:
The expected counts for each class i in a multinomial are just n*p[i]. Therefore the expected sum of the result vector multiplied by the known vector [0, 1, 2] should be np1 * 0 + np2 * 1 + np3 * 2 which simplifies to:
Expected sum = np2 + 2np3
However, I have no idea what the variance would be or what distribution would be appropriate to use in this case.

Interesting question, but it's off topic here; try [stats.SE] instead. I suppose the result you're looking for must have a known conventional solution, but I don't see it; some algebra seems to show that the likelihood function is a polynomial in p2 and p3, which looks like it might be messy to work with -- probably best to look for a known solution as I was saying.
